# Laravel - Setting a default route prefix

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, policy

I'd like to set a default route prefix for all my routes based on the users company e.g.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{company}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CompaniesController@index')->name('company.index');

});
```

Is there some way i can set this value through middleware etc so i don't have to do something like this on every method and the user only has access to their own company.

```
public function index(Company $company)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->company == $company) {
            return $company;
        }
        abort(404);
    }
```

Using Laravel 6.x

Comment: How are you using Spark? Are you using user billing or team billing?

Comment: I'm not using spark

Comment: Sorry, mis-read the question. The answer then, I don’t see what the issue is with the route group? Apply a prefix, add some middleware that checks if the authenticated user has access to the company on the request. Unless I’m missing something?

Comment: It appears you are missing the question. The questions is "Is there some way i can set this value through middleware" if i knew how to do it, i wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: I don’t really understand why you would want to do route registration in middleware? Middleware is for manipulating HTTP requests and responses; not application logic. Register a dynamic route group with a `{company}` parameter (like in your example), and then use middleware to authorise whether the user has access to the company they’re trying to access.

Comment: Thanks All, I went with the middleware route at first but switched to the policy approach as it gave me a cleaner, more extendable solution in the end, I appreciate the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any custom middleware for this you can achieve this with Policies & the build-in `can` middleware of laravel.

In your case it will be something like the following:

```php
// app/Policies/CompanyPolicy.php
class PostPolicy
{
    public function view(User $user, Company $company)
    {
        return $user->company->getKey() === $company->getKey();
    }
}


// web.php
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{company}'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CompaniesController@index')->name('company.index');

})->middleware('can:view,company');


// Controller
public function index(Company $company)
{

    return 'magic';
}
```

For more information about this you can watch the following documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#via-middleware

Answer (score 1):

You can use a middleware in the route level like this:

1) Build your middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\Company;
use Closure;

class CheckUserCompany
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->company == $request->company) {
            return $next(;
        }
         abort(404);
     }
}
```

Probably you don't need `Company` model here since you are getting the company value from your route variable.

2) Register your middleware in your `App\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'company.check' = \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserCompany::class
 ];
```

3) Then your route should look like:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{company}', 'middleware' => 'company.check'], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'CompaniesController@index')->name('company.index');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make a middleware with command `php artisan make:middleware CompanyMiddleware`, set name for it (I named it "company") in Kernel.php and handle 
   method in company middleware must like this:

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
     $request->attributes->add(['company' => auth()->user()->company]);
     return $next($request);
   }
   ```

   in kernel.php :

   ```
   'company' => CompanyMiddleware::class,
   ```

   2. in route apply middleware:

      ```
      Route::group(['prefix' => '/{company}', 'middleware' => 'company'], function(){
        Route::get('/', 'CompaniesController@index')->name('company.index');
      });
      ```
   3. get $company in route methods that define company middleware for it:

      ```
      public function index() {
        $company = request()->company;
      }
      ```

I hope useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about registering routes inside of the *middleware* class, then that is not really possible, because the middleware in itself is applied on already-registered routes.

---

However, you can use [route groups](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-groups) and apply a middleware that redirects to the authenticated user's "company".

**routes.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\RedirectToCompany;

// Use the auth middleware before the RedirectToCompany middleware to make sure users are authenticated

Route::middleware('auth', RedirectToCompany::class)->name('company.')->prefix('/{company}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', ....)->name('index');
    //Your routes here
})->where('company', '(google|microsoft|yahoo)'); //Here i supposed that your company is not really bound, you can omit this
```

> **Note:** You are also able to register multiple route groups inside of the presented route group if your companies have different routes.

**RedirectToCompany.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($user->company != $request->route('company')) {
        return redirect()->route('company.index'); //or even abort(404);
    }

    return $next($request); 
}
```